# Why doesn't C++17 enforce deleted copy constructor?

Tags: c++, c++17, copy-constructor

I expect the following code to result in an error, regardless of whether the copy is optimized or not:

```
struct A {
    A() {}
    A(const A&) = delete;
};

int main() {
    A a = A();
}
```

Indeed, this is what happens in C++14 and earlier:

```
main2.cpp:7:7: error: call to deleted constructor of 'A'
    A a = A();
      ^   ~~~
main2.cpp:3:5: note: 'A' has been explicitly marked deleted here
    A(const A&) = delete;
    ^
```

But in C++17, this peacefully compiles (with both gcc and clang). What change in C++17 is responsible for this, and how can I now enforce the previous semantics?

Comment: `A a = A();` is copy initialisation __since C++17__ and is done in-place no temporary is created.  _"...First, if T is a class type and the initializer is a prvalue expression whose cv-unqualified type is the same class as T, the initializer expression itself, rather than a temporary materialized from it, is used to initialize the destination object: see copy elision..."_ https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization  Also read the C++17 section here - [Mandatory elision of copy/move operations](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision)

Comment: @RichardCritten The semantics of it might have changed in C++17, but haven't `A a = A();` *always* been copy-initialization?

Comment: @RichardCritten And if the copy-constructor is explicitly deleted, shouldn't it disallow any kind of copying, elision or not?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude _"...The copy/move constructors need not be present or accessible:..._ https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision  [re: _"...The semantics of it might..."_ yes I  put the _and_ in the wrong place should have been - _"is copy initialisation and since C++17 ..."_]

Comment: @RichardCritten Does copy initialization have a corresponding operator that can be overloaded/deleted just like the copy constructor does? In a larger example that I'm dealing with, I'd like to explicitly make private all ways of constructing the object since I want to enforce that an lvalue with the class type be never obtained outside the class definition.

Comment: @Simeon Make the constructor(s) (default etc) private and use factory methods to create the object. Doing this would make `A a = A();` fail as `A()` would be a private constructor.